# How to Create a Notepad++ Regex Expression

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I'm looking to highlight all instances within a very large document that contains a `Number)spaceLetter`

For example,

> 1) The cat in the hat.
>
> 2) I like to read.

Both **1)** and **2)** would be highlighted.

Essentially I want to find and replace all of these using the function found in the software itself. Does anyone know the REGEX code to doing this?

Comment: `\d+\) [a-zA-Z]`? Assuming you want the whole sentence `\d+\) [a-zA-Z].*`

Comment: Thank you, this is correct.